# ImportError when use pycharm profile

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

**The problem**

I start a flask app, which works fine when I use "run" or "debug." However, I got the error when use "profile," here is the log message

```
In folder C:/Users/Myname/PycharmProjects/ProjectName
"C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\envs\ProjectName\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 
Professional Edition with Anaconda plugin 2019.2.4\helpers\profiler\run_profiler.py" 127.0.0.1 12055 -m flask run
Starting cProfile profiler
Traceback (most recent call last):
Snapshot saved to C:\Users\Myname/.PyCharm2019.2/system\snapshots\ProjectName1.pstat
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Professional Edition with Anaconda plugin 2019.2.4\helpers\profiler\run_profiler.py", line 173, in <module>
profiler.run(file)
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Professional Edition with Anaconda plugin 2019.2.4\helpers\profiler\run_profiler.py", line 89, in run
execfile(file, globals, globals)  # execute the script
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Professional Edition with Anaconda plugin 2019.2.4\helpers\profiler\prof_util.py", line 30, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\envs\ProjectName\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
from . import json
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

**What I have tried**

I google it and found that it is an old problem.

[Can't profile module using relative imports](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28509?_ga=2.61806444.1370666243.1581348130-2098848986.1573709040)

[Pycharm profile is not working](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003937020-Pcharm-profile-is-not-working)

**How to reproduce it**

If you would like to reproduce it, you can create a flask app using pycharm, and then click "profile."

The default code for flask app is as follows. But I don't think it matters.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The error message can be different due to the change of the flask version or Pycharm version, but the reason is the same: `File "xxx\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>` use relative import and cause the ImportError

**My question**

My question is, is there a way to make it work? Any hacks or tricks are also appreciated. I just want to use the profile now. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### [New solution]

Thanks to @Masklinn, use `-m flask.cli` instread of `-m flask` could solve this problem. However, the configuration in `pycharm flask` use `-m flask` by default and I cannot find out a way to modify it. Therefore, I suggest to use `pycharm python`. The `script path` should be set to your `FLASK_APP`, and add `-m flask.cli` in `addtional options`.

### [Obsolete solution]

One solution is that directly modify the `__init__.py` to make it work. For example, change

```
from . import json
from .app import Flask
```

to

```
from flask import json
from flask.app import Flask
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is a long-standing issue with PyCharm's profiler, it does not run *packages* correctly resulting in sys.path being wonky and relative imports failing: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28509

I guess an option would be to make your own "launcher script" simply copying [what `flask.__main__` does](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/__main__.py).

Though things *might* also work out if you run `-m flask.cli` instead of just `-m flask` (I don't know, I didn't test it): it does the same thing but does not invoke a `__main__` file so it could behave better.

Comment: Yes, use -m flask.cli could solve the problem. I update the answer to show how to configure it in pycharm